# location.reload in ajax is not bringing latest data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a ajax call on success of ajax call I am doing location.reload(true), but its not showing latest updated data, it showing old data and after refresh manually it is showing original data. I have two doubts,

**1: location.reload() loading cached copy?**

**2: I have a form element just for validation shake so that I can stop user from submitting when inputs are null, so this form after submit adding ? to my url is that causing any problem?**

Any suggestions ?

```
if (!errorFlag) {
                $('.loader-section').css('display','block');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo $this->url('catalog-gift-certificates-status-update')?>",
                data:{
                    'id': transactionProductArray,
                    'gift_status': giftStatusArray,
                    'reference_number': referenceNumberArray
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.status === "error" || data.length === 0) {

                    } else {
                        location.reload(true);
                        $('.loader-section').css('display','none');
                    } 
                        $('.loader-section').css('display','none');
                },
                error: function(data) {
                        $('.loader-section').css('display','none');
                }
            });
        }
```

//this is the form code just to check validation but on submit it adding ? to url

$('form#myAdminForm').on('submit',function(){
                    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
                    is_sameAdmin=true;
                    activeInput=false;
                    return true;
                });

Comment: GET requests cache, do you have proper no cache headers?

Comment: And FYI, if you run window.location.reload(), the lines after it are not going to run.

Comment: yes thats my fault but whats the real reason behind not getting data at first load

Comment: @epascarello I have get requests no cache, I confirmed from developer and also saw in header request.